# Semi-transparent QQuickWidget doesn't draw anything on Windows

Tags: qt, qml

I want to create a `QQuickWidget` with no parent, i.e window. I read about the doc(about `QQuickWidget`):

> Making the window semi-transparent, with other applications and the
>   desktop visible in the background, is done in the traditional way: Set
>   Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground and change the Qt Quick Scenegraph's
>   clear color to Qt::transparent via setClearColor().

Here is the code I wrote, it works fine on Qt5.5.0 + Mint17.0 with an runtime warning-"QQuickWidget: Attempted to render scene with no context". When running on Windows10 + Qt 5.4.2, it is completely transparent.

```
//main.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQuickWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    auto quick = new QQuickWidget();
    quick->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint|Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    quick->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
    quick->setClearColor(Qt::transparent);
    quick->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    quick->show();

    return a.exec();
}
//main.qml
import QtQuick 2.4

Rectangle {
    height: 360
    width: 360
    color: "transparent"
    Text{
        text: "hello"
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `view->setWindowOpacity(0.5)`? And what a sence to use `QQuickWidget` in this context? I think that better way to create a window with `QML` is through `QQuickView` or `QQmlApplicationEngine::load()`

Comment: Setting opacity doesn't work. I have a C++ widget and a qml widget, and I need qml widget to stay at top always. `QQuickview` doesn't seem to support `raise()`. @folibis

Comment: Can you please post [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I've tested it and opacity works fine for me so it needs some additional code to test.

Comment: After updating to Qt 5.5.0, everything works. And then I built it with Qt 5.4.2, it became visible, kind of wierd.